# Issues when wrapping the fortran codes contains modules by using f2py

Tags: arrays, numpy, fortran, f2py

I have a fortrran code which need to output a array which dimension depends on a variable in module. There are no problem when I compile these files to generate a .so file. However, when I call the subroutine in the python, it will obtain a error. 
Next is a simplified code used for explaining my questions

```
!fortran code: mod.f90
module constant
  implicit none
  integer(kind=4),parameter :: typenum=8,intype=4
  integer(kind=4) :: cutnum
end module

subroutine test(n,m,a,b)
  use constant
  implicit none
  integer(kind=intype) :: n,m,i,j
  real(kind=typenum) :: b(cutnum,m)
  real(kind=typenum) :: a(n,m)
  !f2py integer,intent(aux) :: cutnum
  !f2py intent(in) :: n,m
  !f2py intent(in) :: a
  !f2py intent(out) :: b
  do j=1,m
    do i=1,n
      a(i,j)=(i+j)*1D0
    end do
  end do
  b=n-a
  return
end subroutine

subroutine init_pes(n)
  use constant
  implicit none
  integer(kind=4) :: n
  !f2py integer,intent(in) :: n
  cutnum=n
  return
 end subroutine
```

Compile with the following directive:

```
f2py mod.f90 -m f2 -h f2.pyf --overwrite-signature
f2py -c --debug-capi f2.pyf mod.f90
```

And the python code:

```py
#python file : test.py
import numpy as np
import f2

print(f2.test.__doc__)

n=5
m=6
# set value of f2.constant.cutnum
f2.init_pes(n)

a = np.zeros((n, m), dtype=np.float64, order='f')
b = np.zeros((n, m), dtype=np.float64)
b = f2.test(a)
print(b)
```

If I run the test.py, a Segmentation fault and an empty array will be obtained
**According to my test, if the output array is one dimension vector or its dimension is independent on the variable in the module, the code can be run normally. otherwise It will break down. **

Comment: Note: the array `b` exists within the subroutine and can be printed. The crash happens after the return.

Comment: Yep, you have the same question?

Comment: No, I was trying to diagnose what was not clear to me from the information you gave us. This is a note to other readers.

Comment: Do you have any ideas to fix the problem?

Comment: Ok, thank you anyway.